# Initializing array of classes in c++, why cplusplus.com code is not working?

Tags: c++

I was doing c++ tutorials in cplusplus.com but some of the codes are not working. And here is one of the code that I'm struggling most.
It's about initialization of array of classes.

I've tried a lot of different ways that I found in web but this code still couldn't be compiled. Of course I can just use for loop, but I really wonder why I can't use this kind of initialization in my c++. Below codes are exactly same code from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

```
// pointer to classes example

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
  int width, height;
public:
  Rectangle(int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
  int area(void) { return width * height; }
};


int main() {
  Rectangle obj (3, 4);
  Rectangle * foo, * bar, * baz;
  foo = &obj;
  bar = new Rectangle (5, 6);
  baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };
  cout << "obj's area: " << obj.area() << '\n';
  cout << "*foo's area: " << foo->area() << '\n';
  cout << "*bar's area: " << bar->area() << '\n';
  cout << "baz[0]'s area:" << baz[0].area() << '\n';
  cout << "baz[1]'s area:" << baz[1].area() << '\n';       
  delete bar;
  delete[] baz;
  return 0;
}
```

compiler error says,

```
class_example.cpp:30:13: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of 'Rectangle [2]'
  baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };
            ^
class_example.cpp:17:7: note: candidate constructor (the
      implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1
      argument, but 0 were provided
class Rectangle {
      ^
class_example.cpp:20:3: note: candidate constructor not
      viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
  Rectangle(int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
  ^
1 error generated.

enter code here
```

Is this because of my c++ version? I think my version is, when I type
c++ --version in terminal It shows me,

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: You need to turn on C++11 support (`-std=c++11` if compiling via command line)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dd5e12506bbe0d8).  How did you compile the code?

Comment: In future please refer to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) rather than the notoriosly bad known resource cplusplus.com

Comment: Thank you so much @UnholySheep !! you are genius It's working! 